# Write and Read a specific line from a text file on android

Tags: android, java-io

I want to read specific line from file like text.txt then write some string to it. any method to do that on android? I'm still play around with LineNumberReader, but still cant find way to do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a combination of inputstream, bufferedreader, stringbuilder, and an outputstream?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @wyoskibum. yes im try with FileWriter, BufferedReader, LineNumberReader and it works now. my really problem is i'm stuck in my SDCard path location to my file.txt

Comment: There really isn't anyway around that unless you root your device.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe anybody get the same case like that..

```
private void Writing() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        String[] lines = new String[888];
        File internalStorage = Environment.getDataDirectory();
        File dir = new File (internalStorage + "/myPde");                   
        File file = new File(dir, "ekfslam.pde");
        File file_temp = new File(dir, "ekfslam_temp.txt");

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file_temp,true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(file));

        file_temp.createNewFile();

        int i = 0;
        String Line = "";
        while (true) {
            Line = lnr.readLine();
            if (Line != null) {
                lines[i]=Line;
                i++;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < 50; j+=5) {
            lines[95] = lines[95]+"\n\t\t Data "+j;
        }           

        if (file_temp.exists()) {               
        } else {
            file_temp.createNewFile();
        }

        for (i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
            bw.write(lines[i]);
            bw.newLine();
            System.out.println(lines[i]);
        }
        file.delete();
        file_temp.renameTo(file);
        bw.close();
        lnr.close();            
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```